# OLE32 Link Error with multiple definitions of IsEqualGuid

Tags: c++, c, winapi, ole

When I try to compile a COM based application with the following code on Windows, I get the following error when I pass `-lole32` to my compiler:

Code:

```cpp
#include <shobjidl.h>
#include <windows.h>
#include <stdio.h>

const IID IID_ITaskbarList3 = {0xea1afb91, 0x9e28, 0x4b86, {0x90, 0xe9, 0x9e, 0x9f, 0x8a, 0x5e, 0xef, 0xaf}};

void *revery_register_icon_progress_win32() {
    ITaskbarList3 *tbl;
    CoCreateInstance(&CLSID_TaskbarList, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,
                     &IID_ITaskbarList3, (void**)&tbl);
    return (void *)tbl;
}
```

Error:

```
/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/include/guiddef.h:161: multiple definition of `IsEqualGUID'
C:/Users/Admin/AppData/Roaming/npm/node_modules/esy/node_modules/esy-bash/.cygwin/usr/x86_64-w64-mingw32/sys-root/mingw/lib/libole32.a(dwzns00301.o):(.text+0x0): first defined here
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

I'm not sure how to solve this, because it appears that the error isn't with my code, but with the library itself. If the file is completely empty I still get this error. Is there anything I can do to fix this?

**EDIT**: I have determined that this arises from linking both DWrite and OLE32 in my program, i.e. if I compile with just `-ldwrite` or `-lole32`, the program compiles and works fine, but if I include both I end up with the aforementioned compile error. This is a problem, because I need both in my program.

Comment: What happens if you re-order the includes?  Include order can sometimes mess things up.  Also, I'd put windows.h first as the most general set of definitions that other includes are going to expect to exist.

Comment: @DaveS unfortunately reordering the includes doesn't help

Comment: Does using `#pragma once` at the very begin of guiddef.h help?

Comment: @DavidRanieri `guiddef.h` is not my file, it's provided by the win32 API (https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/guiddef/)

Comment: Try a search on "multiple definition" for other posts with suggestions.  I'd still move `shobjidl.h` to last in your include order, with `windows.h` first.

Comment: @DaveS I moved `windows.h` to be first in the import list -- thank you! The problem with other solutions I've found to this problem is it requires editing of one of the files that contains the colliding function, which I am not able to.

Comment: I use the latest MinGW gcc-8.1.0 but can't reproduce this error. In addition, `CoCreateInstance(CLSID_TaskbarList, NULL, CLSCTX_INPROC_SERVER,IID_ITaskbarList3, (void**)&tbl);`, remove the "&" since the parameter type is reference, and you don't have to declare IID_ITaskbarList3, but just pass `-luuid` to the compiler.

Comment: @DrakeWu-MSFT I have determined the error arises from having both DWrite and OLE32 linked. I.e., if I just have `-ldwrite` or `-lole32`, the program compiles fine, but if I have both, I get the error in the post.

Comment: Still cannot reproduce it with both `-ldwrite` and `-lole32`, with the same header file(same order), and an empty main function. `gcc test.cpp -ldwrite -lole32 -luuid`. Could you provide a [Minimal, Reproducible Example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?